# asio tcp server hanging

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio, asio

I know this is probably a really simple problem but ive been trying to get the asio examples to work correctly for over a week now. whenever I run the program, the terminal hangs and dosent print anything and dosent send any info to the client. Im using Ubuntu Linux and a basic compiler command

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -I include
```

```
#define ASIO_STANDALONE;
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <asio.hpp>

using asio::ip::tcp;


int main()
{
  try
  {
    asio::io_context io_context;

    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 1326));

    for (;;)
    {
      std::cout << "hi";
      tcp::socket socket(io_context);
      acceptor.accept(socket);

      std::string message = "e";

      asio::error_code ignored_error;
      asio::write(socket, asio::buffer(message), ignored_error);
      break;
    }
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the terminal hangs and dosent print anything and dosent send any info to the client

You need to connect a client first, because the first thing you do is a blocking `accept` which never completes unless a connection arrives.

I've compiled your program (with minor modification for Boost Asio):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c5b45a0a186a8fd)**

```
//#define ASIO_STANDALONE
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

int main() {
    try {
        asio::io_context io_context;

        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 1326));

        for (;;) {
            tcp::socket socket(io_context);
            acceptor.accept(socket);
            std::cout << "hi " << socket.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;

            std::string message = "server message works\n";

            error_code ignored_error;
            asio::write(socket, asio::buffer(message), ignored_error);
            break;
        }
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Using netcat to emulate a client:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 1326 -w 1 <<< "Hello world"
```

We see:

```
hi 127.0.0.1:45448
server message works
```

Or more clearly in separate terminals:[image]

Comment: Thanks I'm really new to networking this really helps